# aws snapshot does not connect to internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, ec2-ami

we have an instance and the instance has a daily snapshots. Anyway there was an error and we are trying to restore the last snapshot but the problem is that when we create a new instance using the snapshot (of course we create an image first) is that the new instance does not connect to the internet even though we have assigned the same ElasticIP for the old server and the same security group!. any idea why this is happening guys ?

Answer (score 0):

after some debugging I found that the virtualization type was the problem it should be set to hvm